# AudioClip can only play once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

In my game I am creating in unity ,Why my AudioClip can only play once?

```
using (var result = synthesizer.StartSpeakingTextAsync(messageToSpeech).Result)
        {
            var audioDataStream = AudioDataStream.FromResult(result);
            var isFirstAudioChunk = true;
            var audioClip = AudioClip.Create(
                "Speech",
                SampleRate * 300, 
                1,
                SampleRate,
                true,
                (float[] audioChunk) =>
                {
                    var chunkSize = audioChunk.Length;
                    var audioChunkBytes = new byte[chunkSize * 2];
                    var readBytes = audioDataStream.ReadData(audioChunkBytes);
                    if (isFirstAudioChunk && readBytes > 0)
                    {
                        var endTime = DateTime.Now;
                        var latency = endTime.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
                        isFirstAudioChunk = false;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize; ++i)
                    {
                        if (i < readBytes / 2)
                        {
                            audioChunk[i] = (short)(audioChunkBytes[i * 2 + 1] << 8 | audioChunkBytes[i * 2]) / 32768.0F;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            audioChunk[i] = 0.0f;
                        }
                    }

                    if (readBytes == 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(200); // Leave some time for the audioSource to finish playback
                        audioSourceNeedStop = true;
                    }
                });
            audioSource.clip = audioClip;
            audioSource.Play();
```

i store it in another script , and then use audioSource.Play(); to play the clip again, but no sound?

even when i try to .Play() in the same script , and have no sound.

any ideas?

Comment: Check if a clip you're creating is still exists after the execution of a method. And check if maybe other call of that method creates the empty clip, so you getting no sound second time. Can't suggest more than that because you didn't provided enough info.